# How does relative thrust contribution of bypass flow depend on thrust settings

Tags: turbofan, thrust-reverser

The context of this question is a wish to estimate the effictiveness of cold stream thrust reversers at low speed.

Given a stationary high bypass two spool turbofan at STP, e.g. the CFM56, how much, as a fraction of the core specific thrust, is the specific thrust of the bypass flow at

- Full rated thrust
- N1 corresponding to max reverse thrust
- Idle

As this will of course depend on the particular engine type, ballpark values and the general trend for low vs. high thrust settings are what I am looking for.

Comparison of N1 vs N2 for different thrust settings for any engine fitting the description is also appreciated.